# C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string' - Behaving weird

Tags: c++, string, header, std

I am trying to learn C++, however, the parameter to a method I have in my own class is misbehaving. When it uses a dataType of 'int', it works fine with no errors, but when I attempt to change it to a 'string' dataType, the program crashes with this error.

> Error 1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string' in temp.h ln
>   8 col 1

The classes I am using are as follows:

WORKING CODE
TesterClass.cpp // Entry Point

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Temp.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Temp tmp;
    tmp.doSomething(7);

    return 0;
}
```

Temp.h

```
#pragma once

class Temp
{
public:
    Temp();

    void doSomething(int blah);
};
```

Temp.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Temp.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

Temp::Temp()
{
    std::cout << "Entry" << std::endl;
    string hi;
    std::cin >> hi;
    std::cout << hi << std::endl;
}

void Temp::doSomething(int blah)
{
    std::cout << blah;
}
```

BROKEN CODE
Temp.h

```
#pragma once

class Temp
{
public:
    Temp();

    void doSomething(string blah);
};
```

Temp.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Temp.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

Temp::Temp()
{
    std::cout << "Entry" << std::endl;
    string hi;
    std::cin >> hi;
    std::cout << hi << std::endl;
}

void Temp::doSomething(string blah)
{
    std::cout << blah;
}
```

When I adjust the parameter 'blah' to be a string, in both the .h and .cpp file, the problem occurs.

I have looked around, but none of the answers seem to solve my problem. I would greatly love help on this an I am out of ideas. I have tried reinstalling C++, messing with:

```
using namepace std;
using std::string;
std::string instead of string
etc.
```

If you know how to solve my problem I would love to hear from you. I am more than happy to provide more information.

Comment: `When I adjust the parameter ..., the problem occurs.` Please show the code where the problem occurs, not something else.

Comment: You need to `#include <string>` in your header file and prefix `std::`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks that was just what I needed ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ performs single-pass compilation, so std::string needs to be declared before you use it at all - including in the header file.

```
// Temp.h
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Temp
{
public:
    Temp();

    void doSomething(std::string blah);
};
```

I would encourage you to be specific in your header files when specifying classes like this, because you might easily come across another library that defines it's own `string` and then you would run into naming conflicts. Save the `using` import statements for your cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

πάντα ῥεῖ had the write answer, thankyou!

They said to use std::string when needed, and to also `#include <string>` in the header file.